# Fast way to populate numpy array with multiple iterations of multiple numbers

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I need to populate a numpy array, execution speed is important to me.  The array will use a dictionary  which will specify how many instances (indexed key value) of the array value (key value) I need.

The script below is my attempt, testing shows it takes 0.14 seconds to run but if I remove the hstack it runs in 0.004 s.  So I conclude that it is the concatenating of the array that is taking the time.  What's a better method?

Note the dictionary below is just a test case, in general I will have about a 100 different values and each value will repeat approximately 10,000 times.

```
td = {}
for ii in range(100):
    td[ii] = 10000+ii
a = np.ones(0)
for aa in td:
    a = np.hstack((a,np.ones(td[aa])*aa))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does the same thing but takes 3 ms vs 200 ms on my machine:

```
td = {}
for ii in range(100):
    td[ii] = 10000+ii

a = np.hstack([np.ones(td[aa])*aa for aa in td])
```

It calls `np.hstack` once on a list of arrays rather than repeatedly joining. Also, note that the order that you iterate through a dictionary is not guaranteed to be in the same order of insertion (use an `OrderedDict` if you want that), so you should be careful.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost another 10x faster (than Josh's solution) to just flat out preallocate your memory.

```
a = np.empty((sum(td.values(),)))
i=0
for k,v in td.iteritems():
    a[i:i+v]=k
    i +=v
```

Why mess around with intermediate storage when you have enough info at the start to size your array?  (`np.empty` is a quick way to size an array without actually setting any values yet)